# Add color to Selenium Webdriver window

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I would like give a color to the Selenium WebDriver window's frame. (Attaching Image)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5jIM.png)

I tired to do it with `chrome_options = Options()`
and
`chrome_options.add_argument("default-background-color FFFFFF00")`

That's my code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotInteractableException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
import requests
import time

# Chrome driver
s = Service('C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe')
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("default-background-color FFFFFF00")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=chrome_options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

It's not working for me.
When happens is that the browser is opening with 2 tabs. The URL of the first one is the "80808000" and the second one is Google.com

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJjxi.png)

There is any solution for it?

Thanks!

Comment: Please share all your code

Comment: I added my code. Thanks

Comment: I really want the same behaviour as the OP.. Reason is to distinguish between staging and production environments at a glance..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `FFFFFF00` is the default background color.
Please try setting it to any other value like `80808000`and see if it makes changes.

```py
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("default-background-color 80808000")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=chrome_options)
```

Then you will be able to set the color you want.

Comment: When happens is that the browser is opening with 2 tabs. The URL of the first one is the "80808000" and the second one is Google.com. I'm attaching a picture of it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that there is an issue with the syntax. I am not sure, but you can try:

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--default-background-color ff0000ff")
chrome_options.add_argument("--default-background-color=ff0000ff")
chrome_options.add_argument("--default-background-color:ff0000ff")
```

The argument `"--default-background-color"` is present in this list:
https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/ (referred from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities)
https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:headless/app/headless_shell.cc;l=363?q=default-background-color&sq=&ss=chromium